# Angular 8 (Latest Update) Does not Support In UC Browser

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, uc-browser

When i run my app with command

```
ng serve
```

In My UC Browser, I am seeing  [image: blank page]. Just have a fav with title. When i lookup in console i found this message

```
Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated and will be removed in M56, around January 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5760718284521472 for more details
```

Note : In Google Chrome it works fine. Uc has 3.46% browser market share and i dont want to lose some user.Infact the official website of angular does not load in UC browser.
My Configuration

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.4
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
```

Comment: That's not a supported browser: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: but it worked on angular 6 @jonrsharpe

Comment: That's as may be, but because it's not supported the developers won't check to make sure it keeps working or (in all probability) prioritise work to get it working again.